# File does not read UTF-8 input in C

Tags: c, utf-8

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100

int main(void) {

   char myWord[SIZE];

   printf("Enter \"blå\": ");
   fgets(myWord, sizeof(myWord), stdin);
   printf("Entered string: %s", myWord);

   return 0;
}
```

And this is my output:

```
Enter "blå": blå
Entered string: bl
```

Why doesn't `fgets` properly read the input? I changed the character encoding to UTF-8 using this guide:

[Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt / Windows Powershell (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window/57134096#57134096)

This helped me print `blå` instead of `bl├Ñ` but I still can't read input from the user. The only solution I can think of is that I need to change the encoding of `stdin`. Do I do that with `locale.h` or is there another way?

I am on windows and VScode and have MINGW32 as compiler.

Comment: Works correctly in bash, so it appears to be your terminal encoding.

Comment: If I enter chcp then the output is "Active code page: 65001". Doesn't this mean that UTF-8 is enabled?

Comment: @Alexander Jonsson, when debugging such, print the length, use a linefeed and use sentinels.  `printf("Entered string: %zu, <%s>\n", strlen(myWord), myWord);`.  What was your result?

Comment: `fgets()` is fine. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/1180620

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica Strlen returns 2 and the output is still bl.